# Yii CHtml textField special characters in value

Tags: php, yii

Code:

```
CHtml::textField('username', $username, array('class'=>'text'));
```

If my input field has **Å** type of special characters the value get disappeared. It solves if I put as `htmlentities($username)` in value field. But it prints the character as `&Aring;`

I think it's because the values are get printed by going through CHtml::encode() function.

How should I print the correct value?. Any help please.

Comment: Try set your charcode in config

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have in the html head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If you work with multibyte strings, this may help:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Put the above 2 lines at the beginning of the code. I always include these at the first 2 lines of my index.php